# Is this Regular expression for Javascript is correct

Tags: javascript, regex

Iam looking for the user to enter 3 characters and they should be letters and not numbers and special characters

```
 if(txt1.match('[A-Za-z]{3}')){}
```

Is the above if condition is  correct ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `i` regex flag to make the matching case insensitive and simplify the regex. Also, without `^` and `$`, any string containing three consecutive letters will match. You need to add `^` and `$` to match the beginning and end of the string respectively. Finally,  if you don't need to capture the text matched, you should use the `test()` method of the regular expression object to get a simple Boolean value:

```
if ( /^[a-z]{3}$/i.test(txt1) ) {}
```

Answer (score 6):

Nope, you haven't used the correct delimiters for a regular expression, e.g. `/reg/`:

```
if(txt1.match(/[A-Za-z]{3}/)){}
```

Although `match()` will construct a regex from any string passed, you might confuse yourself when you need to start escaping characters.

You also need start and end anchors, `^` and `$` respectively, to ensure that the regular expression matches from the start of the string to the end of the string:

```
if(txt1.match(/^[A-Za-z]{3}$/)){}
```

Finally, if you only want a `true` or `false` check (in this case you do), use [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/Test) instead of `match()`:

```
if(/^[A-Za-z]{3}$/.test(txt1)){}
```

`test()` is a method on instances of regular expressions, so the regex comes before the function call.

Comment: According to [MDC](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), passing a string performs an implicit call to `new RegExp()`, though I'd play it safe and make it explicit (as you did) in case there are any browser specific issues out there.

Comment: @patrick: I *was* playing it safe because I don't remember it being part of the specification (just checked - it is), and I wasn't sure if `match` was one of the methods that automatically constructed a regex from the string, thanks :-)

Comment: Had to look it up since you mentioned the spec. :o) *Section 15.5.4.10 String.prototype.match (regexp), points 3 & 4* if anyone is interested. EDIT: Oh, didn't notice that you already checked.

Answer (score 2):

That would match against any string with 3 or more characters, to limit it to strictly 3 alphabets, try

```
if(txt1.match('^[A-Za-z]{3}$')){}
```

Comment: `^[A-Z][a-z]{3}$` matches four characters: one uppercase letter followed by 3 lowercase letters.

Comment: Hmm that's weird, all the other answers suggest that we use / / for regex, but I was able to get this working in chrome, i.e., javascript: if("and".match('^[A-Za-z]{3}$')){alert("HI")} will alert "HI" still and javascript: if("andg".match('^[A-Za-z]{3}$')){alert("HI")} won't...

Comment: Some javascript methods that expect a regex coerce them from a string, if necesary.  But since it's so easy to use the literal `/.../` notation, you should.

Comment: the specification states that `match()` should construct a regular expression object from the argument passed if it isn't one already.  However, the literal notation is less confusing when escaping characters.

Answer (score 2):

Very close

```
if(txt1.match(/[A-Za-z]{3}/)) {}
```

Note: the above will match if the user enters 3 characters that are letters and not number or special characters. It will also match if the user enters something like

```
234abc098
```

If you want to ensure that it is only 3 characters total then make sure to put the beginning of string and end of string markers in the regex

```
^[A-Za-z]{3}$
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (txt1.match(/^[A-Za-z]{3}$/)) { }
```

I changed 2 things.  First A regex in Javascript starts and ends with a slash.  Second, I added a start and end character (^ and $).  This ensures that the stat of the string is followed by 3 letters, and then ends.  Meaning it must be exactly 3 letters.

Answer (score 2):

No. First, the syntax is wrong, it should use a regex literal (actually, a string seems to work here too):

```
txt1.match(/[A-Za-z]{3}/)
```

Next, if you want 3 character and not more, make sure to include the start and end anchors:

```
txt1.match(/^[A-Za-z]{3}$/)
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has a special syntax for regular expressions: `/regex/`. The following shows the correct implementation of regular expressions:

```
if(txt1.match(/[A-Za-z]{3}/)){}
```

There are several RE (regular expression) functions available, on the String object (like `"string"`) and the RegExp object (like `/regex/`). If you just want to test a string against a regexp without saving the result, it's recommended to use the `RegExp.test` function:

```
if(/^[A-Za-z]{3}$/.test(txt1)){}
```

Note: I've added `^` and `$` because it should match all of the characters, containing 3 characters is not enough. `^` indicates the beginning of the string, `$` the end.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to use forward slashes instead of single quotes to directly pass a regular expression to match() in javascript.

Also, what you're currently checking with your expression is, if 3 letters appear in the checked string consecutively. If you want to make sure that the user just enters 3 letters and nothing else, also check for the beginning (`^`)and end (`$`) of the string with your regular expression. The complete expression looks like this:

```
if(txt1.match(/^[A-Za-z]{3}$/)){}
```